# Decoupling threading logic from business logic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, unit-testing, tdd

Is it common practice to couple threading logic with business logic?  I'm asking with test-driven development in mind, wondering if there are benefits/drawbacks to testing business intelligence that is tied to the threading logic.  Consider the following,

```
class Thread { ... }
class FooThread : public Thread {
  /* business intelligence coupled to threading */
}
```

or,

```
class Thread { ... }
class Foo {
  ...
  /* once again coupled */
  Thread th;
}
```

These approaches seem to go somewhat against trying to abstract away dependencies when testing classes.  Would it be possible/acceptable to instead design a class that can be instantiated completely decoupled from the threading, perhaps possibly using templates?

```
template<class SomeFooClass>
class Thread { ... }

class Foo { 
  /* this class can be tested separately */
}

typedef Thread<Foo> FooThread;
```

Would there be any benefits/drawbacks to this?  Could this same approach be used to decouple business logic from other common design patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads and other computational effects tend to give unit test authors a headache.  If you can, keep the thread management encapsulated away from your business logic under test.

If you're looking for ideas about how to do that, consider making a type representing the work that a thread might do (this type could be a Functor, full-blown class or perhaps just a function pointer.)

Place your "pure" business logic within an instance of this "runnable" type, and test it at this interface.  You could then implement a reusable thread pool that (say) accepts these runnables in a queue and executes each.  Many variations on this pattern are possible; I suggest looking in the boost libraries to find existing implementations.

What this separation will generally *not* save you from is the burden of synchronization, which is typically a cross-cutting concern.  Locks have a way of slipping into otherwise-clean business logic.  You can either attempt to deal with them by mocking them out, or try to eliminate locking altogether (on a case-by-case basis) by serializing access e.g. with a dedicated "broker" thread and a queue of runnables.

Comment: Wouldn't the point of separating threading from business logic to test the pure business logic?  Why test the "runnable" interface, or how is this different from a class coupled to its underlying threading?

Comment: The runnable interface would plain/pure code.  You're certainly free to test underneath that if you like.  If you're trying to prove that a worker thread is doing the correct sequence of steps (as opposed to proving that the objects it manipulates are themselves correct) then the runnable acts as a clean container for the actions that worker would take.

Comment: So the Runnable would basically be a common interface for types that can be passed into and executed by a separate thread object?

Comment: Yup.  This isn't a new idea; as I said, take a look in boost to see what they have for you.

Comment: @jwalk a runnable class doesn't have to be run in a thread.  Imagine collecting updates to be run later in a single threaded situation, ie the observer/listener pattern.